# Symfony 4 Form Type translations

Tags: php, symfony

I've Symfony 4.4 and the Symfony/translation component.
I'm trying to extract the translations, and everything works fine, except that the form labels are not extracted.

This is a example of one of the Form Types.

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\ClassifiedAd;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ClassifiedAdType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('price', MoneyType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'currency' => "EUR"
            ])
            ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'label' => "classifiedad.form.type",
                'choices' => [
                    'classifiedad.form.type_'.ClassifiedAd::SELLING => ClassifiedAd::SELLING,
                    'classifiedad.form.type_'.ClassifiedAd::SEARCHING => ClassifiedAd::SEARCHING,
                    'classifiedad.form.type_'.ClassifiedAd::SWAPPING => ClassifiedAd::SWAPPING,
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ClassifiedAd::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain `extracted`, how are your translations loaded, where are they stored ?

Comment: I'm trying to extract them with the symfony/translation component, with the command "translation:update --force de"
All settings are default, so the translations are saved under /translations
The component extracts only the translations defined in twig files or if i use the translator service.

But in the meantime i think, this isn't an issue of me or a bug. I think this is not implemented yet. You can not extract labels in form classes with the symfony/translation component.
For now i used the "php-translation/symfony-bundle" component, and with this it works perfectly.